# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

`Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.`

build:gradle(Module:app)

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        maven {
            //url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2',
            url 'http://download.flutter.io'
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.+'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
        //classpath("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            apply plugin: 'maven'
            //url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2',
            url 'http://download.flutter.io'
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

build:gradle(Project)

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException ("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '4'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.develpment.sported_app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        //release {
            release {
                profile {
                    matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
                }
                minifyEnabled true
                useProguard true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        //}
    }
    lintOptions {
       disable 'InvalidPackage'
       checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

**Solution Tried:**

1. Invalidate Caches/Restart
2. Build -> Clean Project
3. Updated Kotlin Plugin and used latest Kotlin version
4. Run `./gradlew assembleDebug`
5. Run `flutter doctor` and `flutter clean`

Previously I tried to build for release and the release build, but some features weren't working. So I looked  around and found that I was supposed to add the code below in the main method in the MainActivity.kt in the android section, that's when this issue started. I even tried to comment out the method but the error is still there.

`override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine:FlutterEngine){GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);}`

Comment: I had the same problem and what fix it for me was switching flutter back to stable channel `flutter channel stable` (I was on beta because I wanted to use the `expansionTileTheme`).

Comment: I am also having the same error after updating to Flutter 3 from Flutter 2 and updating all my packages and doing all the same exact steps as you!! Were you able to resolve this @hamsoace

Answer (score 6):

I updated all my project packages. That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, running `flutter pub upgrade` then `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 3):

This actually worked for me

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

```
flutter clean
```

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to equalize kotlin version in first row which is `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'` to according to `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` of underlined $kotlin_version

After this, problem will solve...

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by equalize the kotlin version coz i've done it the same as you suggested

Comment: Okay, im going to explain for you. When i started a new project, my ext.kotlin_version='1.6.10' but this gives me an error. It says changing to 1.6.20. After i changed the code, it starts to work

Comment: Still got the same error

Comment: In my case, I adjust the `ext.kotlin_version` to match the package that is causing an error. I do this by checking the Kotlin version inside the `android/build.gradle` file of that package.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also faced same issue, I done with below changes. But it's a temporary bug fix.
[For more reference](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/698#issuecomment-1052832672)

Search for the FlutterLocationService.kt and edit it
change the function:

```
onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>?, grantResults: IntArray?): Boolean
```

to

```
onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray): Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

**update** `ext.kotlin_version` to latest from here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

> android->build.gradle