# Can't use flutter location or geolocator package

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

Whenever I use flutter pub add location or flutter pub add geolocator package, I get this error:

```
     Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9508325ccc4e6492ee61ca313dfda75b/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (48, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (75, 15): Unresolved reference: apply
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (76, 17): Unresolved reference: lockscreenVisibility
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (78, 33): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public open fun createNotificationChannel(p0: NotificationChannel): Unit defined in androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
public open fun createNotificationChannel(p0: NotificationChannelCompat): Unit defined in androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (86, 54): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (87, 17): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (87, 26): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (89, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (91, 14): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public open fun setSmallIcon(p0: IconCompat): NotificationCompat.Builder defined in androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
public open fun setSmallIcon(p0: Int): NotificationCompat.Builder defined in androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (95, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (101, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (109, 33): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (115, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (118, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (120, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (124, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (169, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (172, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (173, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (193, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (194, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (196, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (201, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (203, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (214, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (215, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (216, 32): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (217, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (227, 23): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (229, 18): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (242, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (244, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (250, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (251, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (253, 14): Class 'kotlin.Suppress' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Suppress.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (254, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (257, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (261, 33): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (264, 13): Unresolved reference: mapOf
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (264, 31): Unresolved reference: to
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (264, 63): Unresolved reference: to
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (271, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (272, 19): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (279, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (281, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (282, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (283, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (285, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (286, 29): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (292, 29): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (294, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/*****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (302, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (303, 69): Unresolved reference: it

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).
```

The project runs fine without adding any of those packages. Here's some more info:

`./gradlew --version`:

```
Gradle 7.6.3
Build time: 2023-10-04 15:59:47 UTC
Revision: 1694251d59e0d4752d547e1fd5b5020b798a7e71
Kotlin: 1.7.10
Groovy: 3.0.13
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM: 20.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 20.0.1+9-29)
OS: Windows 11 10.0 amd64
```

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.10
  uuid: ^4.3.3
  image_picker: ^1.0.7
  http: ^1.2.1
  location: ^5.0.3
```

Checked out some similar questions, but didn't help:

[Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893018/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71781763/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-locationcompiledebugkotlin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71781763/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-locationcompiledebugkotlin%60)